# How to convert a function problem into an equally difficult decision problem?

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, computability

A function problem ("compute $f(x)$") can easily be converted into a decision problem of deciding its graph ("is $f(x) = y$ true?"). However, this may change the computational complexity of the problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem#Function_problems).
For example, computing Ackermann function is not PR, but its graph is
(https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76037/inverse-ackermann-primitive-recursive-or-not).

Then, can we convert any function problem into an **equally difficult** decision problem? For example, can we make a decision problem that require computing Ackermann function to solve?

I think some good cryptographic hash function $h()$ may be useful (we can make a problem "is $h(f(x)) = y$ true?" and it will require computation of $f(x)$), but I'm not familiar with hash functions and could not prove it.

I will appreciate any help. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: "Is verifying an answer as difficult as computing it?" That's a very deep problem in computer science. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem

Comment: Are you sure the $P=NP$ thing is relevant here? Consider CLIQUE, which is NP-hard. CLIQUE asks; given a graph $G$ and a number $n$, does $G$ have a clique of size $n$. But the function problem is very similar: Given $G$, how big is its largest clique? These are easily shown to be mutually reducible, and $P=NP$ does not enter into it.

Comment: Yeah, verifying an answer is sometimes easier than computing it. Hence my question.

Comment: A decision problem is solved by a "yes" or "no" answer on every input, 1 bit of inforamtion. The output of a computable function normally has more than 1 bit of information. So you will have to encode the outup of the function on those cases in each input string of the decision problem. One way to mantain equal diffictulty, assuming f(x) has exponencial time lower bound for example, might be to use lower bound exponential time encoding/decoding functions of the output.

Comment: Not exactly "equally difficult," but for recursive $f,$ set $$A_f=\{\langle x, 2n\rangle\mid f(x)\lt 2^n\}\cup\{\langle x, 2n+1\rangle\mid\text{ the }n^{\text{th}}\text{ bit of }f(x) = 1\}.$$ The running time for a computation of $f$ and the running time for the decision problem for $A_f$ should be close. I haven't worked out the details, but, for the hard direction, it looks like the minimum running time for computing $f$ on an input of size $m$ would be bounded by something like $c\,T(m) \log T(m),$ where $T(m)$ is the running time for the decision problem for $A_f$ on an input of size $m.$